# Continue in nested for loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, continue

I have 3 for-loop inside each other:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < ns_match.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < user_interest.length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < ns_match[j].data().user_interest.length; k++) {
            if (user_interest[j] == (ns_match[i].data().user_interest)[k]) {
              ns_score[i] += 5;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I would add a logic such as `if (user_interest[j] == (ns_match[i].data().user_interest)[k]) {` is true, then augment j.

In another word, I am looking for something such as: `if (user_interest[j] == (ns_match[i].data().user_interest)[k]) {` if that is true, then break out of of the K loop, but continue one increment in the J loop.

Comment: Yes, `break;` ... What's your question?

Comment: You only need to use `continue` if you want to skip the rest of the loop body when going to the next iteration. But there's nothing else in the body to skip.

Comment: You can simply put a `break;` inside your `if` statement. This will break out of `k`, and continue `j`.

Comment: just out of passing information, you can label for statements in Javascript like so `loop1: for(let i = 0; i<10;i++){ ....}` and then from anywhere inside said loop call something like `continue loop1`. While I don't think that will be particularly helpful here, it's good information and not a frequently documented thing in Javascript. This is also true for `break` statements.

Comment: In general, [you can always use labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: Oh, I thought break would break out of every single loop in the nest. That's good to know. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the break command to break out of the current loop block.

if you would need to break out of a different loop other than the inner-most one, you would want to look into whats called 'labels'